# Add hyperlink as a TableItem SWT

Tags: java, hyperlink, swt

How can I add a hyperlink to a SWT Table?

I need to have a table with ordinary TableItem objects as its rows, but sometimes I need to have a hyperlink there, so that someone can click on it open the linked page from application level.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you use a simple `Table` or a `TableViewer`?

Comment: @Baz A `Table`, but if it would be much easier with `TableViewer` I guess I could change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to your question: Instead of a `Button`, add a `Hyperlink`.

[SWT - Tableviewer adding a remove button to a column in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to sambi reddy's answer, you can use a `StyledCellLabelProvider` (if you switch to a `TableViewer`) for your column and use a `StyledString` to represent your link. Of course, you will have to handle the mouse events yourself.

Here is an example:

```
// Column for the link
TableViewerColumn col2 = createTableViewerColumn("Link", 100, 1, viewer);
col2.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell)
    {
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        if(element instanceof Person)
        {
            Person person = (Person) cell.getElement();

            /* make text look like a link */
            StyledString text = new StyledString();
            StyleRange myStyledRange = new StyleRange(0, person.getLocation().length(), Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE), null);
            myStyledRange.underline = true;
            text.append(person.getLocation(), StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
            cell.setText(text.toString());

            StyleRange[] range = { myStyledRange };
            cell.setStyleRanges(range);

            super.update(cell);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What if the table is oriented vertically? Is there a way to do this for a row?

Comment: @MarcinKrzysiak Are you using a `TableViewer`? Are the objects ordered in rows or columns? If they are ordered in rows, the example above will do what you want.

Comment: The objects are ordered in columns. Each column is a separate object. I don't use `TableViewer` yet, but if the case I'm writing about is doable, I will. If not, I might consider to change my project's layout a bit.

Comment: @MarcinKrzysiak I couldn't find anything on how to display you objects as columns... Which doesn't mean that it's not possible. Why do you prefer to organise them this way? Any particular reason?