# SWT: Hyperlink in TableViewerColumn with MouseListener and correct column width

Tags: java-8, swt

I want to add a Hyperlink (or a text that is styled like a Hyperlink) in a TableViewerColumn Cell.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584982/2013672) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585374/2013672).

**Summarize:** I either get a clickable Hyperlink for which the text is cropped (the column width is too small) or I get a link that is not clickable (MouseListener missing, no cursor).

Both tries are making use of a StyledCellLabelProvider for the TableViewerColumn. The first try does this:

```
TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
column .getColumn().setText(TITLE);
column .setLabelProvider(new MyHyperlinkLabelProvider());
```

However, the text in the cell is cropped and I have no idea how to set the column width so that the text fits in the cell. I tried with using `pack()`, but it had no effect.

```
private final class MyHyperlinkLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {

    private MyHyperlinkLabelProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        TableItem item = (TableItem)cell.getItem();
        String myText= "Hyperlink text, unfortunately cropped";

        link = new MyHyperlink((Composite)cell.getViewerRow().getControl(), SWT.NONE);
        toolkit.adapt(link);
        link.setText(myText);
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.grabVertical = true;
        editor.setEditor(link, item, cell.getColumnIndex());
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(editor.getEditor());
        editor.layout();
        link.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent event) {
                super.mouseUp(event);
                if (event.getSource() instanceof MyHyperlink) {
                    MyHyperlink link = (MyHyperlink)event.getSource();
                    System.out.println("Label was clicked: " + link.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        super.update(cell);
    }
}

private class MyHyperlink extends Hyperlink {
    public MyHyperlink(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        this.setUnderlined(true);
    }
}
```

The less preferred alternative is given in the second link. If I cannot get the column width correct, I'd go with this.
The second link suggests to try it with `StyledString` instead of `Hyperlink`. The StyledString at least is shown in full width and the column has the correct width. However, you cannot add a MouseListener to a StyledString. Only on the table, but that doesn't help.

```
private final class MyHyperlinkLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {

    private MyHyperlinkLabelProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        TableItem item = (TableItem)cell.getItem();

        String mytext= "This is the hyperlink text";

        /* make text look like a link */
        StyledString text = new StyledString();
        StyleRange myStyledRange =
            new StyleRange(0, phase.length(), Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE), null);
        myStyledRange.underline = true;
        text.append(mytext, StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
        cell.setText(text.toString());

        StyleRange[] range = {myStyledRange };
        cell.setStyleRanges(range);

        super.update(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Table.getItem(Point)` to get the TableItem from a mouse event on the Table.

Comment: It may be a workaround to get the TableItem. But only if there is a way to get the Column as well. And of course change the cursor. But is this a good solution? IMHO it should be easier to go with a Hyperlink and somehow set the columd width correctly.

Comment: Column widths depend on how you are laying out the table. Something like `TableColumnLayout` with `ColumnWeightData` or `ColumnPixelData`

Comment: In a TableViewer you can get the `ViewerCell` from the Point using `TableViewer.getCell(Point)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the column size computed correctly, the cell text has to be set. Although the Hyperlink is what should be displayed `link.setText(myText);` is not enough.  `cell.setText(myText)` is needed, too.

One can see it in the second snippet, for which the column size is correct. It is because of the `cell.setText()` call.