# SWT Table checkbox for all columns

Tags: swt

I am trying to create a two-column-table with checkboxes in both of them
I have created a table with the following snippet:

```
 Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

 TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
 tableColumn.setWidth(300);
 tableColumn.setText("Check Column1");

 TableColumn tableColumn1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
 tableColumn1.setWidth(300);
 tableColumn1.setText("Check  Column2");

 TableItem tableItem=new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
 Image image=getImage(imagePath);
 tableItem.setImage(0, image);
```

what I am getting is the first column the checkbox was created but not in the second one 
Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the standard SWT Table Widget. Try the [Nattable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) from Nebula for a more feature rich table widget.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show CheckBox in `Table` Cell, you could do it in two ways.

1. show image ( check on/off) depending on state of the data that you have and you need listen on mouse click on table cell.
2. you could add `Button ( SWT.CHECK)` as I mentioned below

[SWT - Tableviewer adding a remove button to a column in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)