# SWT, Jface - effective implementation of own renderers for tableviewer columns?

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I would like to render some [`TableViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TableViewer.html) columns, 
so that the cells in this column look like special widgets.

(`Link`s, `Button`s, etc. should be present in each cell)

How would I implement those renderers? 
This implementation should support thousands of tablerows, and do not flicker when scrolling through the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then implementing you own renderers, which 'looks like' real controls, why not use table which can *actually* render custom controls?

http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/compositetable/compositetable.php

And it's really fast.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a possibility, but nebula is purely maintained and marked as Beta...

Comment: CompositeTable is quite stable. At least, it worth it to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add SWT controls in Table by following my post here

[SWT - Tableviewer adding a remove button to a column in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)

User `TableEditor` class. Make sure add Listener on Table for `SWT.measureitem` event and compute height and width. you could actually reuse widgets if you implement it carefully.

Comment: Sorry, placing Widgets abouve the Table in this way is really ineffective! It crasheds allready, when displaying about 1000 widgets in a table...

Comment: You need to effectively create/dispose them when you need them. Create widget when the corresponding cell is visible in Table display area and dispose it when not required.