# JFace DialogCellEditor: how to make buttons always appear?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

I use JFace `DialogCellEditor` to show a button in a cell of a row of my JFace `TableViewer` which triggers a dialog when activated. This behaviour works well with the following code but the button only appears when the cell of the table hosting the button is explicitly selected.

```
public class CompareDialogCellEditor extends DialogCellEditor {
    public CompareDialogCellEditor(Composite parent) {
           super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Button createButton(Composite parent) {
           Button button = super.createButton(parent);
           button.setText("");
           button.setImage(AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(Application.PLUGIN_ID, IImageKeys.COMPARE_ICON).createImage());
           return button;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object openDialogBox(Control cellEditorWindow) {
           MessageDialog.openInformation(cellEditorWindow.getShell(), "Test", "It works");
           return null;
    }    
}
```

Is there a way to force the button to always appear in the table and not only when the cell is selected? (the same behaviour goes for a label set by the overridden method `setContents(...)` )

Thanks

Comment: button is part of cell-editor. Cell editor comes in picture when you focus in a cell using mouse pointer. Moment you tap out cell editor disappears. You can keep your cells always in edit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only edit one `Viewer` cell at a time. `Viewer` won't support editing multiple cells at a time unless you do some customization.

I can think of following solutions.

1. Paint widget ( button, text, combo..etc) like image on table cell  and invoke 
   `CellEditor` when user activates it.
   You can find some examples here about how to paint on `Table` Cell.
   http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html
2. I posted an answer about how to show button in table cell here. you can following the same concept with `CellEditor`
   [SWT - Tableviewer adding a remove button to a column in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)