# Eclipse : DialogCellEditor class.. how to always show the button?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm extending DialogCellEditor  to make a cell in a table looks like this
but the button appears only when I set focus to that cell (ie. when I click on the cell)

How could I always show this button even before setting focus ?

[image]

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464611/jface-dialogcelleditor-how-to-make-buttons-always-appear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `DialogCellEditor` as it is overlaying the normal cell for the table with new controls when that cell has focus.

You could do this using an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` to draw the table cells yourself, but this is going to be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit more than one cell in a Viewer.

But you should look at that answer. It s about showing buttons in a Table Cell.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)

Comment: This question wasn't about editing multiple cells;)

Comment: I think it is. He couldn't show all buttons in all cells.