# SWT Table and Hyperlink widget integration

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I fight with SWT Table and Hyperlink for too long time. I've read all of the topics on stackoverflow and JFace Snippets and Eclipse SWT Snippets and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I try to create SWT Table with column that contains "DELETE" hyperlink in every row.
My problem is that I can't make it look ok.

Maybe I will put my code first:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.TableColumnLayout;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnWeightData;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink;

public class TableWithDelete {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    TableColumnLayout tableLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
    composite.setLayout(tableLayout);

    TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(false);

    TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.BORDER);
    TableColumn columnWeight = column.getColumn();
    tableLayout.setColumnData(columnWeight, new ColumnWeightData(2, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
    columnWeight.setText("Name");

    column = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    columnWeight = column.getColumn();
    tableLayout.setColumnData(columnWeight, new ColumnWeightData(1, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
    columnWeight.setText("Removal");

    //fill with some data

    String[] sampleNames = new String[]{"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5"};

    for (String name : sampleNames) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(0, name);
    }

    TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
    final List<TableEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableEditor>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
        Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(table, SWT.NONE);
        hyperlink.setText("DELETE");
        hyperlink.pack();
        hyperlink.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Some action on DELETE");
            }
        });
        editor.minimumWidth = hyperlink.getSize().x;
        editor.setEditor(hyperlink, items[i], 1);
        editors.add(editor);
    }
    shell.setSize(300, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

}
```

My problem is that if I run that code, I retrieve ugly default look of the hyperlink:

[image]

When I change style that I pass to Hyperlink to SWT.TRANSPARENT:

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(table, SWT.TRANSPARENT);
```

than row in table starts to look ok, but "transparency" seems to be passed to other table parts, and because of that border of the table looks ugly:

[image]

and what's more when I move mouse over Hyperlink, current row of the table is not highlighted anymore.

What do I miss? How to make SWT Table able to show link in a cell (That does not only look like a hyperlink but also has Mouse cursor correctly changed)?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look at

[SWT - Tableviewer adding a remove button to a column in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table/12486929#12486929)

instead button use `Hyperlink`.

Comment: I've seen this thread before I wrote my question. This question is not about "How to remove row from a table" but it is about "How to correctly render Hyperlink in SWT Table".

Comment: Did you try replace Button with Hyperlink? it should work. if your text is not rendered properly you need to set <a>Delete</a> as text to the hyperlink

Comment: I tried, my problem is that row highlight on mouse over does not work when I move mouse over hyperlink. And also TRANSPARENT style in hyperlink breaks table borders.

Comment: @wojtek88 Why do you need a hyperlink? It looks out of place in a desktop application. I support the button idea.

Comment: Can You tell me than how can I make it look like a hyperlink and don't  loose row highlighting on mouse move?