# How to add Button to table column and table cell in SWT Java

Tags: java, button, swt, tableviewer

I have created a table using table viewer, with SWT Java. Now I want to add a button at the end of each row and also in the table column header.Could any one help me how to implement this?

This is how I have started:

```
this.viewer = new TableViewer(this);
this.table = this.viewer.getTable();
TableColumn column = new TableColumn(this.table, SWT.LEFT);
column.setText("Table Header");
this.table.setHeaderVisible(true);
this.table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

Comment: You want to add a button to the header? What would that look like?

Comment: The table column header does not support buttons.

Comment: yes, to the header  ...  we have a dialog that has to pop up when we click on that button at the header level. And also each row cell on click of button , it should open other dialog

Comment: @Lisha You could just listen to click events on the header and then show the pop up.

Comment: @greg-449  : Okay . can we at least add buttons to the each row

Comment: @Baz Thank you , I shall try this

Comment: @greg-449 or Can we add images instead of button and add listeners for the same ?

Comment: @Baz I tried implementing that, but it pops up when i click on table rows,instead i want pop up when clicked on the column header.Could you please help?

Comment: @Lisha without seeing your code? Unlikely.

Comment: @Baz  Could you please let me know if i can add buttons in each row ?

Comment: @Lisha There's loads of information about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480402/swt-tableviewer-adding-a-remove-button-to-a-column-in-the-table), [here](http://alexander.lds.lg.ua/2010/11/add-swt-widgets-to-the-cells-of-the-table/) and [here](http://sahits.ch/blog/blog/2008/11/04/remove-button-to-remove-itself/).